# Can Have Parent Actor more than One Child Actors In Use Case Diagram

Tags: inheritance, uml, actor, use-case-diagram, generalization

In my Usecase Diagram :

[image]

`Bidder` and `Seller` both inherit from `Guest`. Is this Correct? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Login is no use case. There is no added value you gain from a login.

Answer (score 1):

***Preliminary syntactical remark**: UML shows inheritance  with an arrow head that is a hollow triangle. The small plain black arrow heads are confusing and might be misunderstood.*

**What inheritance means**: Your diagram means that a bidder and a seller are both guests. Is this what you mean to model? In other words:

- Are `Bidder` and `Seller` expected to be involved in all their associated use-cases, and on top, all the use-cases of `Guest`?  If yes, it's fine!
- But do you really want that an existing `Bidder` could register as `Bidder`,  or could register as `Seller`?
- If not, consider separation of concerns: distinguish a `Guest` actor, who  could only register, and a `Registered user` who could login (but is login really a use-case?) and do all the common thing that all registered user can do.   `Bidder` and `Seller` could then inherit from `Registered user`.

**Other improvements**:

- associate `Make payment` and `Receive notification` to `Registered user`, because you're not allowed to have several use-cases with the same name. I understand that if the seller makes payment,  it's probably the fee for the platform.
- have a `Pay the auctioned item` and associate it to both the seller and the bidder, because one pays, and the other receives the payment : it's in fact two sides of the same use-case.
- **simplify**:  use-cases should not be features to add to your software, nor functions to be decompsed. It should be independent user-goals (e.g. `Browse items`, `filter items` and `view item details` are probably three features of one more general use-case `View items`)